# TeamViewer Map Cmd to Ctrl

Tags: macos, windows

So I am using TeamViewer to remote control a Windows PC from a mac. I can use the control key on the mac to active the Ctrl key on windows but it feels clunky. What I was wondering is it possible to remap the command key to the Ctrl key only when using TeamViewer?

Comment: Does it *have* to be TeamViewer? The new Mac RDC beta automatically remaps keys to be more Mac-friendly - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/ [It won't auto-negotiate through a firewall like TV though]

Comment: Yes it has to be TeamViewer; I do not have root level access won't be able to convince anyone who does to update the computer.